# pyshark.LiveCapture not capturing packets

Tags: python-3.x, tshark, pyshark

I am running pyshark version 0.4.2.9 on my Linux system. I am trying to capture packets from my wireless interface 'wl01', but pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='wl01') captures 0 packets. Where as tshark captures packets, just fine.

```
>>> import pyshark
>>> cap=pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='wl01')
>>> cap.sniff(timeout=50)
>>> cap
<LiveCapture (0 packets)>
```

I also tried capture.set_debug(),to get the following:

```
>>> capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='wl01')
>>> capture.set_debug()
>>> capture.sniff(timeout=50)
2020-05-14 12:57:37,348 - LiveCapture - DEBUG - Creating Dumpcap subprocess with parameters: /usr/bin/dumpcap -q -i wl01 -w -
2020-05-14 12:57:37,350 - LiveCapture - DEBUG - Dumpcap subprocess created
2020-05-14 12:57:37,351 - LiveCapture - DEBUG - Creating TShark subprocess with parameters: /usr/bin/tshark -l -n -T pdml -r -
2020-05-14 12:57:37,351 - LiveCapture - DEBUG - Executable: /usr/bin/tshark
2020-05-14 12:57:37,353 - LiveCapture - DEBUG - TShark subprocess created
2020-05-14 12:57:37,353 - LiveCapture - DEBUG - Starting to go through packets
Capturing on 'wl01'
dumpcap: The capture session could not be initiated on interface 'wl01' (No such device exists).
Please check that you have the proper interface or pipe specified.
>>> capture
<LiveCapture (0 packets)>
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks!

EDIT 1:
While running the script with sudo I get the following:

```
user@aritri:~/Documents/tshark$ sudo python3 test.py
[sudo] password for user: 
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<Capture.packets_from_tshark() done, defined at /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py:279> exception=TSharkCrashException('TShark seems to have crashed (retcode: 1). Try rerunning in debug mode [ capture_obj.set_debug() ] or try updating tshark.',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 288, in packets_from_tshark
    await self._go_through_packets_from_fd(tshark_process.stdout, packet_callback, packet_count=packet_count)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 306, in _go_through_packets_from_fd
    psml_structure=psml_struct)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 366, in _get_packet_from_stream
    new_data = await stream.read(self.DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/streams.py", line 634, in read
    yield from self._wait_for_data('read')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/streams.py", line 464, in _wait_for_data
    yield from self._waiter
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 293, in packets_from_tshark
    await self.close_async()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 441, in close_async
    await self._cleanup_subprocess(process)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 434, in _cleanup_subprocess
    % process.returncode)
pyshark.capture.capture.TSharkCrashException: TShark seems to have crashed (retcode: 1). Try rerunning in debug mode [ capture_obj.set_debug() ] or try updating tshark.
Exception ignored in: <bound method Capture.__del__ of <LiveCapture (0 packets)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 446, in __del__
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 437, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 441, in close_async
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 434, in _cleanup_subprocess
pyshark.capture.capture.TSharkCrashException: TShark seems to have crashed (retcode: 1). Try rerunning in debug mode [ capture_obj.set_debug() ] or try updating tshark.
```

EDIT 2:
Both of the commands 'tshark -D' and 'sudo tshark -D' give the same ouput.

```
user@aritri:~$ tshark -D
1. wlo1
2. any
3. lo (Loopback)
4. eno1
5. bluetooth0
6. nflog
7. nfqueue
8. usbmon1
9. usbmon2
10. ciscodump (Cisco remote capture)
11. dpauxmon (DisplayPort AUX channel monitor capture)
12. randpkt (Random packet generator)
13. sdjournal (systemd Journal Export)
14. sshdump (SSH remote capture)
15. udpdump (UDP Listener remote capture)

user@aritri:~$ sudo tshark -D
[sudo] password for user: 
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
1. wlo1
2. any
3. lo (Loopback)
4. eno1
5. bluetooth0
6. nflog
7. nfqueue
8. usbmon1
9. usbmon2
10. ciscodump (Cisco remote capture)
11. dpauxmon (DisplayPort AUX channel monitor capture)
12. randpkt (Random packet generator)
13. sdjournal (systemd Journal Export)
14. sshdump (SSH remote capture)
15. udpdump (UDP Listener remote capture)
```

Comment: What happens if you run the script with sudo?

Comment: @RossJacobs, I have edited the answer with the error I get while running with sudo. If you can kindly have a look!

Comment: Post `tshark -D` and `sudo tshark -D`

Comment: @RossJacobs, posted. Both of them give the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface name is `wlo1` but you use `wl01` in your code. `o` != `0`.